# How to find out who created an event?

Tags: civievent

Is there an easy way to find out who created an event like how we are able to see who created an email?

Answer (score 3):

CiviCRM DOES store that information, but doesn't expose it to the user interface.  So you have two choices:

- Check with SQL.  This will give a list of all events with creators:

```
select ce.id, ce.title, cc.display_name from civicrm_event ce JOIN civicrm_contact cc on ce.created_id = cc.id;
```

Add `WHERE ce.id = x` before the semicolon at the end to just show a single event (where `x` is the event's ID).

- I wrote an extension that allows you to view (and change) the name from the user interface called [Edit Event Manager](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/com.megaphonetech.editeventmanager).